# Recursion to add struct in linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, addition

I'm having trouble inserting a struct into a linked list in numerical order. Each struct has a "number" as indicated in the code below. I'm trying to have the struct with the lowest number be the head of the list (ie: be the struct pointed to by "people"). I've been staring at this code on and off all day and I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

```
Person *addPerson(Person *people, Person *addition, int &numList)
{
if (people == NULL && numList == 0)
{
    people = addition;
    numList++;
    return people;
}
if (people->number >= addition->number)
{
    addition->nextPerson = people;
    people = addition;
    return people;
}
else if (people->number < addition->number && people->nextPerson != NULL)
{
    addPerson(people->nextPerson, addition, numList);
}
else if (people->number < addition->number && people->nextPerson == NULL)
{
    people->nextPerson = addition;
    numList++;
    return people;
}
}
```

EDIT**

```
int main()
{
Person *blake = new Person;
Person *kyra = new Person;
Person *elon = new Person;
Person *bill = new Person;
Person *people = NULL;

blake->number = 1;
blake->name = "blake";
blake->lastName = "madden";
blake->nextPerson = NULL;

kyra->number = 2;
kyra->name = "kyra";
kyra->lastName = "madden";
kyra->nextPerson = NULL;

elon->number = 3;
elon->name = "elon";
elon->lastName = "musk";
elon->nextPerson = NULL;

bill->number = 4;
bill->name = "bill";
bill->lastName = "gates";
bill->nextPerson = NULL;

int num = 0;
int &numList = num;

people = addPerson(people, blake, numList);

people = addPerson(people, kyra, numList);
people = addPerson(people, elon, numList);
people = addPerson(people, bill, numList);

cout << people->name << '\n' << people->lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the return value from `addPerson()` in the third `if` block. Try:

```
people->nextPerson = addPerson(people->nextPerson, addition, numList);
return people;
```

You also need the `return people;` in there otherwise you'll run off the end of your function and not return anything sensible (my compiler warned me about that, you should change your warning settings so yours does too).

With the above change, your code appears to run correctly.

Comment: Oh, that worked. Would that solution cause problems, though, if I wanted to add a node that wasn't necessarily directly after the head of the list?

Comment: Also, kind of a side question, but does having issues with relatively simple things like this indicate that I'm going to have a lot more trouble with harder concepts? I feel like I should have been able to solve this much more easily.

Comment: I think it's totally normal to overlook things like this when you're just starting out, especially with recursion. I didn't see the bug at first either and only when I tried to run your code did it become obvious what was happening. As for your uncertainty as to whether this works in all cases, I suggest writing a unit test for your linked list inserter. :)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't ever assigning the returned head. It should be

```
people->nextPerson = addPerson(people->nextPerson, addition, numList);
```

Comment: @BlakeMadden: Perhaps you could tell us what the problem actually is. Currently, we're looking at the code and guessing.

Comment: When I run the code, the head of the list is the entry that should be 3rd on the list. I'll provide my main():

Comment: I added my main() to the original question. I'm trying to make it so that when the last line in main() executes it says "Blake '\n' Madden"

Comment: The problem with Greg Hewgill and Antimony's original solutions is that I don't necessarily want people->nextPerson to be assigned to the return value. In the case that the additional node didn't belong immediately after "people", I would potentially be overwriting the spot of another node in the list

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is the arguments to the function.  You're desiring to modify the pointer in the node in the previous caller in the recursive call-order, but you are simply passing the pointer value of the next node.  That doesn't allow you to actually modify the pointer-member of the previous node.

Change your function so that it looks like this:

```
void addPerson(Person** people, Person *addition, int &numList)
```

Then when you call `addPerson` in the third block, do it like so:

```
addPerson(&(*(people)->nextPerson), addition, numList);
```

And finally when you access the `people` argument, make sure to-do an extra dereference, for instance:

```
*people = addition;
```

or

```
if ((*people)->number >= addition->number)
```

Comment: assigning the return value is another possible approach.

Comment: That's definitely true ... still, the problem is he's not modifying the pointer value in the node from the previous call ...